# Days stuck with a 'simple' login / logout PHP script

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a pretty simple login/logout script for this little private 'niche' site so it doesn't require a lot of security.

```
session_start();

// Array with users and passwords
$lgns = array(
'firstuser' => '5d0a158df212de401a9509a88a8d9f96b060f6c5',
'seconduser' => 'f8a913721596fffbf18a4777e6f163316154e6e5',
'thirduser' => 'f8a913721596fffbf18a4777e6f163316154e6e5',
);

$user = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$passu = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$pass = sha1($passu);

// Check if credentials are valid
// If not...
if( !isset($lgns[$user]) or $lgns[$user] != $pass )
{
    // Check if session is valid
    // If not...
    if ( !(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '') )
    {
        echo "Wrong creds, no session; redirecting...";
    }
    else
   {
        // If credentials are not valid but there IS session
        echo "Wrong creds, but there IS session, so stay.";
   }

}
// If credentials are valid, set session.
else
{
   echo "Correct credentials";
    $sessionUser = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION["user"] = $sessionUser;
}
```

This is the logout script in a separate php file:

```
session_start();

unset( $_SESSION["user"] );
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Problem is: No matter what I try, I keep getting the "Wrong creds, but there IS session, so stay." message. I don't know if I'm not checking the session properly or if I'm not closing de session correctly.

I've been searching and struggling with this for days and I'm starting to feel stupid. I've made this work before! So I had to ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo out all of the variables (`$lgns[$user]`, `$pass` and `$_SESSION['login'])` to make sure they are what you expect. And use [the example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) from the manual to destroy sessions.

Comment: I just added more code for clarity. Changed $_SESSION['login'] for $_SESSION['user'] which is how it's supposed to be but the problem remains.  The users array, the login form and the user/password check work as intended.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of it?

Comment: Do you have session_start() hidden somewhere on your login?

Comment: @Sampad I don't have the time since I'm also working on another project but it's shouldn't be necessary, the code is quite simple. The login process works, the problem can only be **in the IF statements** or the logout script (which I doubt).

Comment: @nerdlyist There's not session_start() in the page where the login form is. There is one at the beginning of the first code I posted in my question, but it's supposed to be there, isn't it? I just edited the post to show it. The login form is in a separate file.

Comment: Where ever you call `$_SESSION` you need `session_start()`. Does this work now?

Comment: `<?php
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION["user"]);
   unset($_SESSION["pass"]);
    echo 'You have cleaned session';
   header("location:login.php");
?>`

Comment: Oh my god, I am stupid. Turns out my logout button which should link to "logout.php" was only linking to "index.php" (login form). Thanks everyone anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look into the following code given below, I hope it will help you!!

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <title>Quiz</title>
            <body>
                <center>Log In Page</center>
                <form action="" method='POST'>
                Email ID : -<input name="email" type="text"><br/><br/>
                Password : -&nbsp; <input name="password" type="text"><br/>
                <input type='submit' value="Log In" name="login">
                </form>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Database_name");
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
    $conv_md_pass=md5($pass);
    echo "$conv_md_pass";
    $select_user="SELECT * FROM mst_user where email='".$login."' AND pass='".$conv_md_pass."'";
    $run_user=mysqli_query($con,$select_user);
    $check_user=mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    echo "/$check_user";
    if($check_user>0)
    {
        echo "Successfully logged in";



    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong username and password";
    }

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

> SignOut

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I wonder if you read my question. Your script makes no use of sessions and that's the sole point of my question. The users array (mini database), login form and the user/password check work correctly. The problem is that although I terminate the session, the script still thinks there is a session when I run it without sending the username and password from the form.  It's supposed to echo "Wrong creds, no session; redirecting...".